# Let $z\in\mathbb C$, show using induction that the product of the roots of $z^n =1$ is $1$ when $n$ is odd

Tags: complex-numbers, induction

Let $z\in\mathbb C$, show using induction that the product of the roots of $z^n =1$ is $1$ when $n$ is odd.

I am taking a class, in which we were asked to prove this using an induction. The other material we have learned is De Moivre and trigo representation of complex numbers. I saw other answers, but they are outside of the scope of the class.

Comment: More generally, the product of the roots of $z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1z+a_0$ is $(-1)^na_0$.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of $z^n=1$ are $\exp(k 2 \pi /n)$ for $k=0,\dots,n-1$.

Therefore, their product is $$\exp(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k \frac{2 \pi}{n})=\exp(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\frac{2 \pi}{n})=\exp((n-1)\pi)=1$$ because $n-1$ is even.

The same argument proves that the product is $-1$ when $n$ is even.

Comment: Thank you. However exp is outside the scope of the subjects...

Answer (score 0):

If $\omega$ is a root of $z^n=1$, then so is $\bar\omega$. Moreover, $\omega\bar\omega=1$. When $n$ is odd, there is only one real root, $z=1$.
Therefore, in the product of all roots, pairs of conjugate roots reduce to $1$, leaving just the real root $1$.

The same argument proves that the product is $-1$ when $n$ is even.

Comment: Thank you! That's great.

Comment: I don't doubt the solution but the question does say clearly that it is to be done by induction. (I can't imagine how that is possible, of course).